# I want to send data using JSONObject and/or REST on our sample webpage

Tags: android

What i'am trying to do here is to send a String data on our sample webpage. i'am quite sure that i didn't miss anything on my codes and i'am not having an error when i run the application, but still i was not able to send data to our webpage. http://icommute-ph.com/

i have two classes one is to test if i could send a user input data string using JSON here are the codes:

```
    private class reqData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://icommute-ph.com/api/v1/todos/");

        try 
        {
            // Add your data
            JSONObject user = new JSONObject();
                try 
                {
                    user.put("Name", tstData.getText().toString());
                } 
                catch (JSONException e) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            // Create StringEntity
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(user.toString());  
                se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
                    httppost.setEntity(se);     

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException cpe) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            cpe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}//end of class reqData
```

this is another class which i'am using to send data using REST note: i'am really sure that this class would work since i tried to do it like this in one of our other webpage.

```
public class reqDataREST extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(
                "http://icommute-ph.com/api/v1/todos/");

        try {
        // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Name", tstData.getText().toString()));
                    postRequest.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            BasicHttpContext httpContext = new BasicHttpContext();
                httpContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, new BasicCookieStore());

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(postRequest, httpContext);
            //int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        }
        catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
        return null;
    }
}// end of reqRoute class
```

when i click a button the user input data should be sent to our sample webpage.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tstData = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.testData);
        sndRequest = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSend);


    sndRequest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            new reqData().execute();
            new reqDataREST().execute();

            //ALERT MESSAGE
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Sending Request, Please Wait...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });//end of onClickListener     

}
```

}

could please anyone help me here i'am just new to json stuff...
here's some details in our sample webpage: http://icommute-ph.com/api/v1/todos/?format=json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the end i solved this by myself... our webpage is in JSON so trying to send it using just to its base url won't do. so i changed the url to http://icommute-ph.com/api/vi/todos